# Write a Python program that reads a positive integer n and finds the average of all odd numbers between 1 and n

Tags: python, debugging

This is the question:

> Write a Python program that reads a positive integer n and finds the
> average of all odd numbers between 1 and n. Your program should not
> accept a negative value for n.

And here is my code, which curiously doesn't work:

```
    k = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
while k <= 0:
    print('Please enter a positive integer!! \n')
    k = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
else:
    b = 1
    sum1 = 0
    while b <= k:
        if b % 2 == 1:
            sum1 = sum1+b
        b += 1
    avg = sum/k
    print(avg)
```

Example: input: 8 and output: 2.5, while it should be 4. Any tips?

Comment: You're dividing by k to take the average but there are less than k numbers added.

Comment: Should be `avg = sum1 / (k / 2)` since the numbers your adding are half of `k`

Comment: Actually you should divide by `ceil(k/2)`

Comment: @Barmar there is no function called ceil... Please elaborate

Comment: @BTables this doesn't work for odd input...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yeah there wasn't much that I could have written... Please enlighten me

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis Sorry, `math.ceil()`

Comment: @Barmar and this is used to find the variable c which I have named in my answer, correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same as `c`.

Comment: BTW, there's a mathematical formula for this sum, so you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we use while True, the program will run until it receives a positive number. and when we get a positive number, then we execute the instructions and turn off the loop using a break

1 version with list:

```
n = int(input())

while True:
    if n <= 0:
        n = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    else:
        numbers = [i for i in range(1, n + 1) if i % 2 == 1]
        print(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
        break
```

2 version with list:

```
n = int(input())

while True:
    if n <= 0:
        n = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    else:
        numbers = []
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                numbers.append(i)
        break

print(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

3 version with counter

```
n = int(input())

while True:
    if n <= 0:
        n = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    else:
        summ = 0
        c = 0
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                summ += i
                c += 1
        print(summ/c)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used sum (builtin function name) instead of sum1 (your variable name) in the 2nd last line. Additionally, you need to count the total number of odd numbers and divide using that number instead of the input.

Comment: That must be a copying error, or he'd be getting an error message instead of an incorrect average.

Comment: Most likely, I edited my answer to address the incorrect average issue.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanMaqsood cheers, i figured out the number of odd numbers but i wouldn't have seen sum1 without you. Thanks a lot

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I reviewed the question and here is the answer:

```
k = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
while k <= 0:
    print('Please enter a positive integer!! \n')
    k = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
else:
    b = 1
    sum1 = 0
    c = 0
    while b <= k:
        if b % 2 == 1: #determines if odd
            sum1 = sum1+b
            c += 1 #variable which counts the odd elements
        b += 1 #counter
    avg = sum1/c
    print(avg)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).